# Simple approve/reject form for SharePoint workflow?

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I'm currently creating (in Visual Studio) a simple approval workflow within SharePoint so that I can execute some custom code once the user has approved an item. However, it seems that when I don't specify an approval form to use, SharePoint just selects a default one with a "Complete Task" button, but no "Reject" button.

Is there some sort of default approve/reject form I can reference in my code to give users both choices, instead of writing my own page or copy/pasting from the web?

P.S. I'd like to stay away from InfoPath. This is a really simple workflow that shouldn't take much time, and I feel like going the InfoPath route would take much more time than it's worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such built-in form.  The choices for your own approval form are InfoPath or a custom ASPX.  From personal experience using either approach requires considerably more effort to develop than it really should but if InfoPath is available, use it because in my opinion it is quite a lot quicker and I believe has the added advantage that the task can be edited in Outlook (2007).